# Alpakka S3 connection issue

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, playframework, akka, alpakka

I'm trying to use Alpakka S3 to connect to a minio instance in order to store files, but I'm running into problems since I upgraded the library version from `1.1.2` to `2.0.0`.

Here is a simple service class with just two methods that try to create a bucket. I tried both approaches, first loading alpakka settings from local config file (`application.conf` in my case) and second via direct creation of the settings via `S3Ext`.

Both methods fail and I'm not sure about the problem. Regarding the error, it seems the settings are not loaded correctly, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

What I'm using:

- play framework 2.8.1
- scala 2.13.2
- akka-stream-alpakka-s3 2.0.0

Here is the service class:

```
package services

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.alpakka.s3._
import akka.stream.alpakka.s3.scaladsl.S3
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink
import akka.stream.{Attributes, Materializer}
import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.{AwsBasicCredentials, AwsCredentials, AwsCredentialsProvider}
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.AwsRegionProvider

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

@Singleton
class AlpakkaS3PlaygroundService @Inject()(
    materializer: Materializer,
    system: ActorSystem,
) {

  def makeBucket(bucketName: String): Future[String] = {
    S3.makeBucket(bucketName)(materializer) map { _ =>
      "bucket created"
    }
  }

  def makeBucket2(bucketName: String): Future[String] = {

    val s3Host      = "http://localhost:9000"
    val s3AccessKey = "access_key"
    val s3SecretKey = "secret_key"
    val s3Region    = "eu-central-1"

    val credentialsProvider = new AwsCredentialsProvider {
      override def resolveCredentials(): AwsCredentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(s3AccessKey, s3SecretKey)
    }

    val regionProvider = new AwsRegionProvider {
      override def getRegion: Region = Region.of(s3Region)
    }

    val settings: S3Settings = S3Ext(system).settings
      .withEndpointUrl(s3Host)
      .withBufferType(MemoryBufferType)
      .withCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
      .withListBucketApiVersion(ApiVersion.ListBucketVersion2)
      .withS3RegionProvider(regionProvider)

    val attributes: Attributes = S3Attributes.settings(settings)

    S3.makeBucketSource(bucketName)
      .withAttributes(attributes)
      .runWith(Sink.head)(materializer) map { _ =>
      "bucket created"
    }
  }
}
```

The config in `application.conf` looks like this:

```
akka.stream.alpakka.s3 {
  aws {
    credentials {
      provider = static
      access-key-id = "access_key"
      secret-access-key = "secret_key"
    }
    region {
      provider = static
      default-region = "eu-central-1"
    }
  }
  endpoint-url = "http://localhost:9000"
}
```

If the first method of the service is used (`makeBucket(...)`) I see this error:

```
SdkClientException: Unable to load region from any of the providers in the chain software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain@34cb16dc: 
[software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.SystemSettingsRegionProvider@804e08b: Unable to load region from system settings. Region must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_REGION) or  system property (aws.region)., software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.AwsProfileRegionProvider@4d5f4b4d: No region provided in profile: default, software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.InstanceProfileRegionProvider@557feb58: Unable to contact EC2 metadata service.]
```

The error message is quite precise and I know what's wrong, but I just don't know what to do because I specified the settings as outlined in the documentation. Any idea?

In the second method of the service (`makeBucket2(...)`) I try to explicitly set the S3 setting, but this does not seem to work either. The error looks like this:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[S3Exception: 404 page not found
]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:335)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:253)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:424)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:420)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.run(Promise.scala:453)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:92)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:94)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:92)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:47)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
Caused by: akka.stream.alpakka.s3.S3Exception: 404 page not found
```

Here it looks like the defined setting are not taken into account at all, since the service does not seem to be found. This is actually the approach I used in former version of my software where I used `akka-stream-alpakka-s3` version 1.1.2 and it worked as expected.

Of course I want to use Alpakka S3 not only to create buckets, but for the sake of this showcase and to outline my problem, I kept it simple with only this example. I guess, if this problem is solved, all other methods provided by alpakka will just work.

I really red the documentation several times but I'm still not able to fix this issue, so I hope someone here can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help in the lightbend forum [here](https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/alpakka-s3-connection-issue/6551).

The issue was solved by setting the following parameter:

```
alpakka.s3.path-style-access = true
```

Since the documentation says, this value is going to be deprecated, I did not consider to specify it.

In my original post, I outlined two approaches setting the params, one via `application.conf` and one programmatically via `S3Ext`. First does work by setting the value as shown above, the second approach looks like this:

```
val settings: S3Settings = S3Ext(system).settings
      .withEndpointUrl(s3Host)
      .withBufferType(MemoryBufferType)
      .withCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
      .withListBucketApiVersion(ApiVersion.ListBucketVersion2)
      .withS3RegionProvider(regionProvider)
      .withPathStyleAccess(true)
```

Here the last line is crucial, even though I'm getting a deprecation warning.

But in the end, this was solving the issue.

Answer (score 2):

At least as of 2.0.0, the configuration path for Alpakka S3 is now `alpakka.s3` not `akka.stream.alpakka.s3`.

```
alpakka.s3 {
  aws {
    credentials {
      provider = static
      access-key-id = "access_key"
      secret-access-key = "secret_key"
    }
    region {
      provider = static
      default-region = "eu-central-1"
    }
  }
  endpoint-url = "http://localhost:9000"
}
```

Comment: Changing the config path solved the issue of the region, but now I'm getting the same error as mentioned for the second method. `S3Exception: 404 page not found`. But I am certain, that the url and credentials are correct, since it is used by other services and I can also open the minio ui in the browser. Somehow the endpoint-url is not loaded correctly. ???